# How to setup client certificate authentication in ASP.NET framework

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, ssl

I'm trying to figure out how to set up my Azure Web App to require client certification. The idea is to force the client's browser to send a SSL certificate (that's installed on their machine) to the web app. The web app then validates attributes in the certificate to make sure the client is authorized to access the web app.

The purpose is to enhance the security of our web app since user cannot login from a device that doesn’t have the SSL cert explicitly installed (even if they have the username/password somehow).

I'm not sure where I should begin with this. I understand SSL handshakes and the highlevel concepts but I don't really understand how to implement this in my current ASP.NET MVC web app. A tutorial that would point me in the correct direction would really help out. Or even the steps required to achieve this as I am not sure where to begin (setting up SSL certificate with IIS? Getting client to send the SSL certificate? Where did the certificate come from?) All of these questions...

**UPDATE**: I found this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth

But I don't know where to begin...

Comment: Where to begin? That article shows both Azure side setting and sample code. You probably should find a more senior guy locally to teach you, or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: @Lex Li I tried using this but I realized that enabling client certificates through the app service isn't possible unless I have a more expensive plan for my App Service. Is there any possible way to do this without having to scale up?

Comment: Well, that goes beyond the scope of a question. You want to remove a limitation of Azure service, and only Microsoft holds the answer.

Comment: @Lex Li how would you do this in a local environment? Could you perhaps provide some articles that will help me?